# NETLOGO - Agents draw random value from .csv

Tags: csv, netlogo, agent

I have a csv called "Males.csv" with three columns "turning_angles" "speed" "step_length"

I have created a very simple model of agents in a blank environment

```
  to set-up 
  clear-all
  reset-ticks
  ask patches [set pcolor green]
  ask n-of home patches [set pcolor brown]
  ask patches with [pcolor = brown] [
  sprout n-turtles [set breed turtle set shape "arrow" set sex one-of ["male" "female"]]]
end
```

I want to write procedures called `step` and `turn` where agents move and draw their parameters from the columns in the csv. Is it possible to convert a csv column to a list and then randomly select from the distribution of the data?

for example - as pseudo code.

```
turtles-own [step-length turn]

to step 
ask turtle fd random step-length from_column "step_length" "Males.csv"
end 

to turn 
ask turtle fd random turn from_column "turning_angles" "Males.csv"
end

to go 
ask turtles [step turn]
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the [CSV-extension](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/csv.html). You also find an example model in the models library (see [CSV Example](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/models/CSVExample).

The extension reads your CSV file line by line, so you need to loop and extract the values of your columns one by one into a list. You would make your life a little easier if you save your distribution not in columns but rows, but of course it also works with columns. You can use `one-of` to draw a random item of that list.

I attached a code example of how you could solve your problem below.

```
extensions [ csv ]
globals [
  step_length_ls
  turning_angles_ls
]


to read_csv
  ; close file connections
  file-close-all
  ; open your csv file
  file-open "males.csv"
  ; read first line of csv file (headers), alternatively just hardcode the index of columns
  let header csv:from-row file-read-line
  ; determine position of columns according to header
  let idx_step_col position "step_length" header
  let idx_turning_col position "turning_angles" header
  ; initialize global variables as lists
  set step_length_ls []
  set turning_angles_ls []  
  
  ; read data in via a while loop
  while [ not file-at-end? ] [
    ; here the CSV extension grabs a single line and puts the data of that in the data variable (list)
    let data csv:from-row file-read-line
    ; append the values to the global list
    set step_length_ls lput (item idx_step_col data) step_length_ls
    set turning_angles_ls lput (item idx_turning_col data) turning_angles_ls
  ]
end

to step 
  fd one-of step_length_ls
end 

to turn_turtle 
  ; not sure if fd is what you want here, but according to your pseudocode it is
  fd one-of turning_angles_ls 
end

to setup
  read_csv
  create-turtles 1
end

to go 
  ask turtles [step turn_turtle]
end
```